# Info about thread count in OSGi

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, osgi, bundle, threadpool

Is there a command in OSGi to get information about the thread pool? E.g. minimum number of threads, current number of threads ... etc.

Comment: What threadpool would you be referring to.  OSGi doesn't have any inherent thread pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An OSGi framework does not know anything about thread pools. A framework implementation has some threads for asynchronous task like event dispatching but otherwise does not create threads/thread pools for the bundles. Any threads/thread pools created by bundles are unknown to the framework.